# Store parameter into variable with space

Tags: bash, variables, quotes

Consider the following commands with output :

```
$ du -sm ~/Documents 
458 /home/utilisateur/Documents
$ du -sm ~/Documents --exclude='aa bb' --exclude='cc dd'
153 /home/utilisateur/Documents
```

I wish to replace the excludes by one variable like this, in order to get the same output.

```
$ du -sm ~/Documents "$c"
```

But, if I set variable with following, I failed. I tested :

```
$ c=--exclude='aa bb'\ --exclude='cc dd'
$ du -sm ~/Documents "$c"
458 /home/utilisateur/Documents

$ c="\"--exclude='aa bb' --exclude='cc dd'\""
$ du -sm ~/Documents $c
458 /home/utilisateur/Documents
du: cannot access '"--exclude='\''aa': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'bb'\''': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'dd'\''"': No such file or directory

$ c="--exclude='aa bb' --exclude='cc dd'"
$ du -sm ~/Documents "$c"
458 /home/utilisateur/Documents
$ du -sm ~/Documents $c
458 /home/utilisateur/Documents
du: cannot access 'bb'\''': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'dd'\''': No such file or directory
```

Please, could help me to fix my mistake. I know it's about quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
du --exclude='aa bb' --exclude='cc dd'
```

You have multiple arguments, at least some of which contain whitespace.
There's no way to put them in a single string variable so that the separation between the arguments is retained.

If you do

```
args="--exclude=aa bb --exclude=cc dd"
du $args
```

The string is split on all spaces, giving four different arguments to `du`:
`--exclude=aa`, `bb`, `--exclude=cc` and `dd`.

On the other hand, with

```
du "$args"
```

The contents of `args` aren't split, at all, so `du` gets a single argument.

Quotes don't help, as they are not processed after expanding the variable, but they go to the command literally, as you saw from the errors `du` gave.

The correct solution is to use [an array](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html#Arrays):

```
args=("--exclude=aa bb" "--exclude=cc dd")   # initialize it
args+=("--exclude=ee ff")                    # you can even append to it
du -sm ~/Documents "${args[@]}"
```

See also: [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) on unix.SE

Comment: So, an array is the key ! Also, `args=(--exclude='aa bb' --exclude='cc dd')` works too. Thanks ikkachu !

Comment: @NicolasSmith, yes, `-a="foo bar"` is exactly the same as `"-a=foo bar"`, or `-a=foo\ bar` or `-a=foo" "bar`. IOW, as long as the space is quoted, it doesn't matter if the rest is as there aren't any other special characters. From the shell's point of view, the equal sign is not special

Answer (score 2):

**If you're using it in a script** put your variables in quotes:

```
du -sm "$path" "$exc"
```

Also change the assignment to `exc` to

```
exc="--exclude=aa bb"
```

Another option is to change the [Internal Field Separator](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184863/what-is-the-meaning-of-ifs-n-in-bash-scripting). Just set it to the newline character like so (remembering to restore its original value after you're done):

```
OLDIFS="$IFS"
IFS="
"
# do your scripting stuff
# restore IFS
IFS="$OLDIFS"
```

**EDIT**: This won't work if you use more than one `--exclude`.

Comment: I update my question because several `--exclude` need and same issue. Could you help me ?

Comment: Quoting the quotes works if you want to pass the quotes to the command. Usually you don't. Also, I don't see how changing `IFS` helps here?

Comment: @ilkkachu My answer was for a script (which I really didn't mention, so my fault), hence the `IFS`. Also after my answer OP changed his question to include two `--exclude` statements and then it stopped working. Your answer works great so +1 for that :)